# Accessing array column in SQL - for multiple values

Tags: sql, arrays, search, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake database that has an array column 'EQUIVALENT' (correct terminology?) as per the below jpg

I worked out I can access this for a single value, using the code below,

```
    WHERE EQUIVALENT[0] IN('A') OR EQUIVALENT[1] IN('A') OR EQUIVALENT[2] IN('A')
```

But, this is clumsy, and I need 10 OR statements to look in each location.  I actually need to pass 200 Equivalents, and find the resulting 'Part's, therefore was hoping for a variant of the following that would return the found EQUIVALENT and related PART

```
    SELECT * FROM .....   WHERE EQUIVALENT IN('B','ZZ','G'....)
```

.  I'm relatively new to SQL, therefore the terminology in Snowflake help is really not helping!

[image: SQL array search]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ARRAYS_OVERLAP(<array1> , <array2>):

Compares whether two arrays have at least one element in common. Returns TRUE if there is at least one element in common; otherwise returns FALSE. The function is NULL-safe, meaning it treats NULLs as known values for comparing equality.

```
WHERE ARRAYS_OVERLAP(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('B', 'ZZ', 'G', ...), equivalent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_intersection.html).

```
where array_size(array_intersection(equivalent, array_construct('B', 'ZZ', 'G' . . .))) > 0
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, but it looks like array_intersect is not accepted by Snowflake

Comment: @MarkHeptonstall . . . It exists, I just spelled it wrong:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_intersection.html.